# Cannot run automated tests that are contained within classes

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, mstest

I`m new to selenium and I can't seem to be able to run my tests that are contained in different methods and classes.

Before I added the methods into classes I could run the test fine. But as a class assignment we were required to separate the test into different classes.

Would really appreciate your help!

Here are the different methods and classes I use:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using System.Threading;

namespace firstProject
{
[TestClass]
class automation
{
    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    [TestMethod]
    public void PurchaseIFrame()
    {
        driver.Url = "http://automationpractice.com/index.php";
        var homefeatured = driver.FindElement(By.Id("homefeatured"));
        var items = homefeatured.FindElements(By.TagName("li"));
        items[0].FindElement(By.Id("icon-eye-open")).Click();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void PurchaseBlouse()
    {
        driver.Url = "http://automationpractice.com/index.php";
        IWebElement login = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("login"));
        login.Click();

        IWebElement email = driver.FindElement(By.Id("email"));
        email.SendKeys("tester@test.com");

        IWebElement password = driver.FindElement(By.Id("passwd"));
        password.SendKeys("12345");

        IWebElement submitLogin = driver.FindElement(By.Id("SubmitLogin"));
        submitLogin.Click();

        IWebElement homearea = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("footer_links"));
        IWebElement homeBtn = homearea.FindElement(By.ClassName("btn"));
        homeBtn.Click();

        IWebElement catArea = driver.FindElement(By.Id("block_top_menu"));
        IWebElement women = catArea.FindElement(By.ClassName("sf-with-ul"));
        women.Click();

        var results = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("ajax_block_product"));
        var blouse = results[1];
        IWebElement img = blouse.FindElement(By.ClassName("img-responsive"));
        img.Click();

        IWebElement addToCart = driver.FindElement(By.Id("add_to_cart"));
        addToCart.Click();

        Thread.Sleep(4000);

        IWebElement layerCart = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("layer_cart_cart"));
        IWebElement buttonContainer = layerCart.FindElement(By.ClassName("button-container"));
        IWebElement buttonPro = buttonContainer.FindElement(By.ClassName("button-medium"));
        IWebElement clickBut = buttonPro.FindElement(By.TagName("span"));
        clickBut.Click();

        IWebElement proCheck = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("cart_navigation"));
        IWebElement proBtn = proCheck.FindElement(By.ClassName("button-medium"));
        IWebElement clickCheck = proBtn.FindElement(By.TagName("span"));
        clickCheck.Click();

        IWebElement submitAddress = driver.FindElement(By.Name("processAddress"));
        submitAddress.Click();

        IWebElement mark = driver.FindElement(By.Id("cgv"));
        mark.Click();

        IWebElement submitProceed = driver.FindElement(By.Name("processCarrier"));
        submitProceed.Click();

        IWebElement bankWire = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("bankwire"));
        bankWire.Click();

        IWebElement a = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("cart_navigation"));
        IWebElement b = a.FindElement(By.ClassName("button-medium"));
        IWebElement c = b.FindElement(By.TagName("span"));
        c.Click();

        driver.Quit();


      }
  }
}

[TestClass]
public class AutomationClass
{
    public IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    public Main main;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void before()
    {
        driver.Url = "http://automationpractice.com/index.php";
        main = new Main(driver);
    }
}

    public class CartProcess
{
    public Checkout prceedToCheckout()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Checkout
{
}

public class Dress
{
    private IWebDriver _driver;

    public Dress(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        _driver = driver;
    }

    public CartProcess AddToCart()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Main
{

    private IWebDriver _driver;

    private IWebElement search_query_top => _driver.FindElement(By.Id("search_query_top"));
    private IWebElement submit_search => _driver.FindElement(By.Name("submit_search"));
    public Main(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        _driver = driver;
    }

    public  Result Search(string dressName)
    {
        search_query_top.SendKeys(dressName);
        submit_search.Click();
        return new Result(_driver);
    }


}

class number
{
    public int i;
    public number(int number)
    {
        i = number;
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class PageobjectTest :AutomationClass
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
       Result result = main.Search("summer");
       Dress dress =  result.select(2);
       CartProcess cartprocess = dress.AddToCart();
       Checkout checkout = cartprocess.prceedToCheckout();


    }
}

public class Result
{
    private IWebDriver _driver;
    private IWebElement product_list => _driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("product_list"));
    private List<IWebElement> dress => product_list.FindElements(By.TagName("li")).ToList();
    public Result(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        _driver = driver;
    }

    public Dress select(int v)
    {
        dress[v].FindElement(By.ClassName("product-image-container")).Click();
        return new Dress(_driver);

    }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. What *exactly* should be happening and what is it doing. Just saying it cannot run the tests is not sufficient.

Comment: How can I call a method to run it asa test run?

Comment: What is the method that you are struggling to call?

Comment: You've posted WAY too much code. You need to reduce this down to a [mcve]. Do something simple like create only 2 tests, each that launches a different URL and closes. Does it work? How are you triggering the tests to run? Are you getting any error messages? Once you've tried all this, edit your question and update it with the information (updated/simplified code, error messages, other useful info).